# How to add multiple foreign keys for one record in express js using sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a table called `Stories` there are few columns and 3 foreign keys: category, sub category and language.

To make association, I have added sequelize function as below which added `CategoryId`, `SubCategoryId` and `LanguageId` columns to the `Story` table.

```
story.belongsTo(category, { as: 'Category' });
story.belongsTo(subCategory, { as: 'SubCategory' });
story.belongsTo(language, { as: 'Language' });
```

How can I add story to story table?
Below is my code.

```
const Category = require('../models/category');
const SubCategory = require('../models/subCategory');
const Language = require('../models/language');

exports.postStory = (req, res, next) => {
    const storyTitle = req.body.title;
    const description = req.body.description;    
    const categoryId = req.body.categoryId;
    const subCategoryId = req.body.subCategoryId;
    const languageId = req.body.languageId;


    Category.findOne({
        where: {
            id: categoryId
        }
    }).then(category => {
        return SubCategory.findOne({
            where: {
                id: subCategoryId
            }
        })
    }).then(subcategory => {
        return Language.findOne({
            where: {
                id: languageId
            }
        }).then(language => {
            //save operation here
            const story = new Story({
                story_type: storyType,
                title: storyTitle,
                description: description,
                categoryId: categoryId,
                subCategoryId: subCategoryId,
                languageId: languageId,
                createdBy: 1
            });
            return story.save()
                .then((result) => {
                    res
                        .status(201)
                        .json({
                            message: "Story added to database",
                            statusCode: 201,
                            CreatedBy: 1,
                            result: result,
                        });
                })
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        if (!error.statusCode) {
            error.statusCode = 500;
        }
        next(error);
    });
```

Although it is adding stories to Story table but it is not adding categoryId, Sub categoryId and languageId, it is adding only null values for those fields as per below screen capture.

[image]

I cannot figure out how to add CategoryId, SubCategoryId, LanguageId to story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key you are using while creating your story instance is in `camelCase` but you have defined the alias in `PascalCase`.

Change either alias in you association definition

```
story.belongsTo(category, { as: 'category' });
story.belongsTo(subCategory, { as: 'subCategory' });
story.belongsTo(language, { as: 'language' });
```

Or Change key in story instance

```
const story = new Story({
  story_type: storyType,
  title: storyTitle,
  description: description,
  Category: categoryId,
  SubCategoryId: subCategoryId,
  LanguageId: languageId,
  createdBy: 1
});
```

**Note:** Add foreign key constraint for all associations to not allow insert/update on null value.

```
story.belongsTo(category, {
  as: "category",
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false
  }
});
```

Comment: Both of your solutions does not worked for me.. my code is adding records to database but it is not adding categoryId, subcategoryId and languageId, its blank when it get added to table. your first solution returns same result and second solution fall into last else block // send error response as all promise queries did not complete either category, subCategory or language query fails

Comment: I have added screen capture in question, could you please take a look?

Comment: @PrasadGavande did you checked which of the 3 queries causing the issue.

Comment: it is not showing any error, i am also getting IDs , but when I try to add it in Story.save(), it is not getting added.. Is it  correct way to add ? Because when we have association with sequalize, it would be added like Category.addStory () method if it is associated with single table.

Comment: @PrasadGavande I have updated the answer with the problem statement and solution.

Comment: Oh Man! it was such silly mistake. I was using wrong case, i overlooked its case sensitive Thanks for correcting me.